# signal timeout and socket gethostbyname()

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following code that given a host name checks its IP.  If the host name is something that does not exist, there is a timeout of around 10 seconds to the [socket.gethostbyname()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=gethostbyname#socket.gethostbyname) call. That is way too long for my needs. A timeout of one second would be more than enough. Thus, I wrapped the code with a [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) expecting that to be raised. However, when I run the following code the handler is indeed called but it appears that [socket.gethostbyname()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=gethostbyname#socket.gethostbyname) blocks so it never gets cancelled.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
import socket
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal {}.'.format(signum))
    raise UserWarning("DNS timeout!")

hostname = 'some-silly-host-name-that-does-not-exist'
ip = None
try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(1)
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    signal.alarm(0)
except (socket.gaierror, UserWarning) as err:
    print(err)
finally:
    print("IP is {}".format(ip))
```

Comment: You can actually set a timeout on the socket instead of using signals: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout